# Mysql : Select query with like

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have this kind of data in my database "mydb" :

```
id | name
---------
1  | abcdef
2  | bcdefg
3  | cdefgh
4  | defghi
5  | efghij
```

I do a simple SELECT query like this one :

`SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE name LIKE '%defgh%'`

So i get those results :

```
id | name
---------
3  | cdefgh
4  | defghi
```

I would like to know if there is a way, with mysql, to inject html code which encompasses the string searched with "LIKE" statement directly in the result ?

So the results would be :

```
id | name   | html
----------------
3  | cdefgh | c<mark>defgh</mark>
4  | defghi | <mark>defgh</mark>i
```

Comment: `replace(name, 'defgh', '<mark>defgh</mark>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, something like this should do :

```
SELECT id, name, replace(name, 'defgh', '<mark>defgh</mark>') as html
  FROM mydb 
  WHERE name LIKE '%defgh%'
```

Comment: Ah yes that will do !
But i use PDO prepared query ... i should have mention it.
I think it will be better to do another question ...

Comment: Here is the other question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76954518/pdo-mysql-select-query-with-like-statement